# How do I open a Windows 7 transacted file in C#

Tags: c#, .net, file, windows-7, transactions

I understand that Windows 7 supports transacted files. How do I use them in C#?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By writing [interop wrappers](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista/KTM.aspx) around the unmanaged functions. I've also [blogged once about it](http://www.bratched.com/en/home/dotnet/47-transactional-ntfs-part-12.html). Here's [another example](http://bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2007/02/21/windows-vista-introducing-txf-in-c-part-3-createfiletransacted-demo.aspx).